# Pergunta canônica para Media Source Obfuscation

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, fechamento, perguntas-duplicadas

Topei com a seguinte pergunta na fila de análise de Votos para Fechar: [Proteger uri do player de conteúdo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88757/201). Nesta, entendo que a intenção é obfuscar a URL do arquivo de mídia.

A possível duplicata é [como incluir a fonte de vídeo usando javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/65846/201), e aqui entendo que a intenção é injetar com JS o arquivo de mídia no HTML.

Na verdade, não tenho certeza se é possível editar *"como incluir a fonte [...]"* para deixar claro que se trata de ***obfuscação*** de alto nível como pede *"Proteger uri do player [...]"*.

A resposta em [como incluir a fonte de vídeo usando javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71299/201) é ok mas eu ofereceria uma recompensa pedindo alternativas.

Então, são duplicatas mesmo? Alguém consegue pensar numa boa edição em *"como incluir a fonte [...]"* para convertê-la em uma melhor P&R canônica?

<sub>(canônica = "olha, esta é a pergunta/resposta que a gente considera como *definitiva* sobre esse assunto")</sub>

Comment: AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF !

Comment: @DeeSouza, opa, tudo bem? Parece que deu problema no seu teclado... :P